# Finding integers satisfying $m^2 - n^2 = 1111$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, factoring

We have to find the integers $m$ and $n$ which will satisfy the given condition:
$$m^2-n^2=1111.$$ 
What could be the answer and how? i tried using trial and error and that took a long time.

Comment: what are the factors of 1111??

Comment: got it ! excellent

Comment: $56^2-45^2=(56+45)(56-45)=101\times 11=1111.$

Comment: Similar type of problem: [GRE Quantitative Problem: integers such that $P^2 - Q^2 = 1155$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2152902)

Answer (score 6):

N.B. This is an answer to a slightly different question, hopefully for instructional purposes. It gives the necessary ideas, but not the solution.

---

Let's do it for a different number. Replace $1111$ by $11$. Then

$$11 = m^2 - n^2 = (m - n)(m + n)$$

Now the factors of $11$ are $1$ and $11$, so we have

$$m - n = 1 \quad\quad m + n = 11$$
or
$$m - n = 11 \quad\quad m + n = 1$$

or the cases where $1\cdot 11$ is replaced by $(-1) \cdot (-11)$. For example, the first case leads to a solution $m = 6, n = 5$, and the difference of squares representation
$$6^2 - 5^2 = 11$$

Now $1111$ is not prime, so it's more complicated. But this should at least get you started.

Answer (score 1):

$$(m+n)(m-n)=101\cdot11$$
therefore m=56 and n=45

Comment: Now that was simple!!

Comment: This does not answer the question as you formulated it. You are missing negative solutions, i.e. $3$ other solutions.

Comment: in negative case the answer would be flipped

Comment: "Flipped"=?$\,\,\,$

Comment: m in positive case will be and n in positive case will be m in negative

Comment: You might want to re-think it. If $m^2-n^2=1111$, then $n^2-m^2=-1111\ne1111$

Comment: @AdityaBidwai, There are four solutions in terms of (m,n) you have found: (m,n), (m,-n), (-m,n), (-m,-n).

Comment: Actually, there are more solutions since $556^2-555^2 = (556+555)(556-555) = 1111 \cdot 1 = 1111$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Yeah, I just realised as well that there were $8$ solutions.